# How to install Qt modules for a python application

Tags: python, qt, qml

I am working on a codebase that uses PyQt5 and QML for its GUI. I want to use the Qt3D module, but when I attempt to import it in my QML file, I am told the module is not installed. pip installing the PyQt3D library did not change that, though I expect that QML libraries won't be installed by pip. I didn't have Qt Creator, so I installed that and one of the addons I could have was Qt3D. I installed it and I see the library folder, but I don't know where to put it to let my QML code access the library. Is there a default path for QML libraries? How would I find out where the libraries are for my code?

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows, Linux, Mac?

Comment: @SebastianDietrich whoops, yeah. Linux and windows for the end result. I develop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the linux end of the system I'm using actually has the library installed already. Go figure. I'm going to use that as a workaround for now. Not really an answer, unfortunately, but this is the solution for me.